# How can I get voice recognition features

Tags: plugins, unity-game-engine, voice-recognition

How can I get voice recognition features into the Unity Game Engine? Is there a plugin or a framework (hopefully freeware) that I could use? If so, any ideas on how to install it? Also, how much of a problem would there be with background noises in the game interfering with the voice inputs into the game? Are there any examples of games on the market that use this? (besides for Spain 3d for the Torque Game Engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using pocketsphinx which can be compiled for the [iPhone](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2010/05/vocalkit-shim-for-speech-recognition-on-iphone/). PocketSphinx is written in C, I'm not familiar with Unity but I guess you might need some kind of PInvoke layer to interface between the two.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will take a look at pocketsphinx.

Comment: I think I will test out the CMU Sphinx, which is the full version, whereas pocketsphinx is for mobile devices.